# Create array of state objects in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, observableobject, swiftui-state

In my project I have a 2D array of my custom class, `GridTile` representing a grid. This is the class:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class GridTile: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tileNumber = 0
    var tileFrame = CGRect.zero
    var isBeingHovered = false
    
}
```

I want my view to update when `tileNumber` is changed, but not to update when `isBeingHovered` is changed. That is why I have it as an observable object with `tileNumber` published.

My problem is actually creating the 2D array and attaching the tiles to the view. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
struct GameView: View {
    
    @State var gridTiles = [[GridTile]]()
    
    let gridWidth = 9
    let gridHeight = 9

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            drawGrid()
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Creates the grid at the specified size
            for row in 0..<gridHeight {
                // Makes each row
                gridTiles.append([GridTile]())
                for col in 0..<gridWidth {
                    // Makes each cell
                    @StateObject var cell = GridTile()
                    gridTiles[row].append(cell)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it is giving me the warning:
`Accessing StateObject's object without being installed on a View. This will create a new instance each time.` How can I do it differently to fix this?

Comment: You don’t need to use @StateObject there. Just create them without it and put them in the array.

Comment: Also… what is drawGrid()

Comment: @Fogmeister The 2d array has 81 items, so how can I create each of those as StateObjects without it? drawGrid() is just a view builder function that I didn’t think was important for the question. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: No @Fogmeister we don't need view model objects

Comment: @Fogmeister the only articles I read are Apple's documentation however I'm really glad the MVVM crowd are finally changing their ways and now trying to correct their damage.

Comment: @malhal Apple’s documentation and sample code is full of ViewModels just this morning I was looking at the VideoPlayer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/videoplayer) I am not for or against but I think they have their place. I think people overuse them but giant Views with a ton of logic are unsightly.

Comment: @JackElia SwiftUI wrappers should always be at struct level. The wrapper has no effect where it is now.

Comment: @loremipsum Apple recommend many small View structs for "tighter invalidation". They also recommend group related vars into a custom struct for testability, usually they name it a Config but if they did name it ViewModel in the docs it is a struct definitely not an object. Usually the MVVM crowd are not aware of mutating func so they keep using object instead of struct.

Comment: @malhal the VideoPlayer ViewModel is a StateObject therefore a class not a struct.

Comment: And just FYI I didn't downvote because I was "attacking you from the MVVM crowd" as you claimed in your deleted answer. I downvoted because the first statement you made "In SwiftUI we need to use value types for view data" is just completely wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I was going to suggest making your GridTile a struct but it would be simpler to just use the built in [GridItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/griditem).

In SwiftUI it is recommended to use value types for view data because SwiftUI takes advantage of value semantics for its dependency tracking and diffing features. If you used objects you would lose these features and likely have consistency bugs.

Comment: The absoluteness of your statements make your comments questionable. Here is a documentation page that says the extract opposite of what you are saying [Managing Model Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

Comment: Of course because here we are talking about view data not model data.